# What is the maximum number of documents that can be stored in a MongoDB collection?

Tags: mongodb

I have not been able to locate the answer using Google search. I know that there is a default limit of 16k or so collections in a DB but what is the limit on number of documents that can be stored in a collection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no hardcoded limit.

You're likely to have problems with your RAM and/or disk well before you hit this (non-existent) limit.

You can also increase namespace size and get more collections (but you probably know this already).